# Is there any Jetty IIS Connector available for IIS server?

Tags: java, iis, sharepoint, jetty

There is a Web application in Sharepoint.  It have an HTML I-Frame (Colorbox) which shows page, from different URL, which is a Java Web Application deployed in Jetty.

There is a 'Close' button in Java Web application which should close the I-Frame opened from sharepoint i.e to access parent element to close like given below
setTimeout(function () {parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();}, 1500);

While accessing parent element, we are getting Permission error in firebug like
Error: Permission denied to access property 'parent' ($ or tostring)

What internet says regarding this:
1) Cross Domain Issue: But application is in single domain, there is already another application deployed in Tomcat which is using above method and able to achieve functionality. There is Tomcat IIS connector installed and configured on IIS sharepoint server, so it looks like it is permitting all requests.
2) Javascript Issue: I have tried multiple available on Internet but all return same exception

So watching all this it is concluded that it must be some Jetty IIS Connector or some other settings need to be done

If anyone can provide valuable suggestion in this case i shall be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to cross domain issue. I was not understanding posts available on internet. Following are details:

**Solution**: I used Domain name instead of IP Address. Firstly, i was using 179.11.12.221 i.e IP, then i started using gugumal.portal.no and it worked.

**On Sharepoint side**: There are no separate settings, it is worker files, same used for TOMCAT, where we will give Machine name and AJP Port name and it will work

**Jetty Side**: Do remember to put AJP jar in \lib\ext to get it work

Thanks :)